# What is module's "themes" folder used for?

Tags: module, prestashop

PS documentation says that when developing a module you can create the `/themes/[theme_name]/modules` subfolder and that it is used for:

*"Sub-folder for overriding .tpl files and languages files, if necessary."*

and that it:

*"enables you to handle the module's template files in various ways, **depending on the current theme**."*,

but i don't really understand its practical usage. What would be a use case of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop a Prestashop website you should never change core files. This mean that you can only create new modules in the `/modules/` folder but not alter existing one. Because if you update a module you altered, all your changes will be gone.

Each time Prestashop needs to load a module template file it will first look in the current theme `/themes/your_theme/modules/the_module/path_to_tpl.tpl` if an override of this template exists. If not it will load the template from the `/modules` directory.

This recommandation is also valid for `.css` and `.js` files.

---

The [documentation you mentioned in the comment below](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module) is wrong and should be updated. You can't put a `themes` folder inside a module.

Here is the `_isTemplateOverloadedStatic()` method from `Module` class called everytime we need a module template:

```php
/*
** Template management (display, overload, cache)
*/
protected static function _isTemplateOverloadedStatic($module_name, $template)
{
    if (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/'.$template)) {
        return _PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/'.$template;
    } elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/hook/'.$template)) {
        return _PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/hook/'.$template;
    } elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/front/'.$template)) {
        return _PS_THEME_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/views/templates/front/'.$template;
    } elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/views/templates/hook/'.$template)) {
        return false;
    } elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/views/templates/front/'.$template)) {
        return false;
    } elseif (Tools::file_exists_cache(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/'.$template)) {
        return false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see in this code, Prestashop will never look into a `themes` folder inside your module when loading a template.

Comment: I undestand that behaviour but i'm talking about the subfolder at the module's root folder: `/modules/mymodule/themes/[theme_name]/modules` as explained in the PS documentation: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module. Maybe am i misreading that info?

Comment: That's an error in the documentation, I'll update my answer accordingly.